# NavigationManager: How can I use GpsSignalListener with route simulation on an emulator?

Tags: android, here-api

With HERE Android SDK Premium, when using `NavigationManager#simulate()` method, if I add a `NavigationManager.GpsSignalListener`, the listener callbacks are not called even when I turn on/off my GPS while running on an emulator.

How do I receive GPS signal events while running `NavigationManager` in simulation mode?

Comment: Never tried this `GpsSignalListener`. Let me check

Answer (score 3):

Listening to the turning on/off of the GPS can be done via LocationManager for the status (enabled/disabled) of the GPS/Network provider. This is different from the HERE Android SDK's GpsSignalListener which is for GPS signal lost (e.g when in a tunnel) and restore (i.e when you exit the tunnel) events.

So for listening to the on/off of the GPS of your phone/Android emulator, you need to subscribe to the broadcast messages from the Android system and check for `LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION`. See sample code snippet in an Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    IntentFilter iFilter = new IntentFilter(LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PROVIDER_CHANGED);
    this.registerReceiver(gpsOnOffReceiver, iFilter);
}

private BroadcastReceiver gpsOnOffReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {

            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            boolean gpsOn = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            boolean networkOn = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (gpsOn || networkOn) {
                // GPS is ON
                Log.d("GPS", "GPS turned ON");
            } else {
                // GPS is OFF
                Log.d("GPS", "GPS turned OFF");
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Ah I see. The HERE SDK docs certainly don't make this obvious! There is no mention of what GpsSignalListener even means.

Comment: Yes, a bit more explanation on the GpsSignalListener  would help. We will take care of that. Thanks.

Comment: But this doesn't actually answer the question - Is there a way to trigger GpsSignalListener when I'm using NavigationManager.simulate()?